# Deploying to Azure WebApp + swf player

Tags: web-applications, web-deployment, azure-web-app-service

This is not my expertise field so, basically I'm trying to test this web app flash-player-based, the document sent by our partner works great hitting from the file explorer or debuging in VS'17.

the following is the HTML code for the launcher.htm, however when I try to put it in Azure Web App with VS'17 all files and folders deployed ok but when I launch the same file it is totally blank.

As far as I know is some problem with the **src** clause of the only iframe it has, because it gets the property on '$document.ready with *JavaScript*. when it runs locally there's src, when runs from Azure src is absent.

Might be some kind of trigger preventing to publish on a web server or might be some silly thing that I cannot handle, my JS expertise 3/10

Thanks so much!

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/launch_wrapper.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/helper.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var settingInfo; //NavexGlobal change, storing settings.xml information.
        var cbt_data = new Object;
        function removeTags(str,tag){
            var re= new RegExp('<'+tag+'[^><]*>|<.'+tag+'[^><]*>','g')
            var text =str.replace(re,'');
            return text;
        }
        function updatePageTitle(pageTitle)
        {
            document.title = removeTags(pageTitle,'font');
        }

        //NavexGlobal change, handling config.js to load completion.
        function handleConfigScriptAdded()
        {
            setDefaults();
            setTitle();
            cbt_data.rubrics = settingInfo.rubrics;
            cbt_data.mcp_swf = settingInfo.mcp_swf;
            cbt_data.video_base = settingInfo.video_base;
            cbt_data.version = versionInfo;
            if(settingInfo.mobileEnabled != undefined)
            {
                cbt_data.mobileEnabled = settingInfo.mobileEnabled;
            }
            cbt_data.tc_config_xml = settingInfo.tc_config_xml;
            cbt_data.document = document; //reuired for updating the title with pageid for QA
            var url = "launch-mobile.html"+location.search; //launch url
            document.getElementById("ifrm").src = url;
            //
            if(!checkFlashVersionSuppot() && cbt_data.mobileEnabled != undefined && String(cbt_data.mobileEnabled).toLowerCase() == "true")
            {
                $(window).bind('orientationchange', function() {
                    if ( orientation == 0 ) {
                        orientation = "Portrait";
                    }
                    else if ( orientation == 90 ) {
                        orientation = "Landscape";
                    }
                    else if ( orientation == -90 ) {
                        orientation = "Landscape";
                    }
                    else if ( orientation == 180 ) {
                        orientation = "Portrait";
                    }
                    if(document.getElementById("ifrm").contentWindow.updateOrientation != undefined)
                    {
                        document.getElementById("ifrm").contentWindow.updateOrientation(orientation);
                    }
                });

                document.getElementById("ifrm").src = "launch-mobile.html"+location.search;
                //document.getElementById("ifrm").src = "html5/launch-mobile.html"+location.search;
            }
            else
            {
                var url = "launch.htm"+location.search; //launch url
                document.getElementById("ifrm").src = url;
            }
            var url = "launch_elt.htm"+location.search; //launch url
            document.getElementById("ifrm").src = url;
        }


        //NavexGlobal change for loading config.js files dynamically.
        function launch(settingData)
        {

            settingInfo = settingData;
            addScriptTag(settingInfo.configPath, handleConfigScriptAdded); //adding script tag for config.js
        }

        //NavexGlobal change for setting title of the html file.
        function setTitle()
        {
            if(settingInfo.courseTitle != null)
            {
                cbt_data.courseTitle = unescape(unescape(settingInfo.courseTitle));
            }
           // $(document)[0].title = cbt_data.courseTitle+" v"+settingInfo.navpanelVersion;
            $(document)[0].title =  'NAVEX Global'; //  change by aneesh
        }

        //NavexGlobal change for loading setting.xml containing mcp wrapper details.
        $(document).ready(function(){
            init();
            alert('hola papi');
        });

        // for checking flash support


        function checkContentType()
        {
            var strPath ;
            if(checkFlashVersionSuppot())
            {
                strPath="launch_elt.htm"+location.search; //launch url
                //alert("go with Flash version");
            }
            else
            {
                strPath="launch-mobile.html"+location.search; //launch url
                //strPath="html5/launch-mobile.html"+location.search; //launch url
            }
            return strPath;
        }

        function checkFlashVersionSuppot()
        {
            var hasFlash = true;
            try {
                var fo = new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash');
                if(fo) hasFlash = true;
                //alert("status @1 "+ hasFlash )
            }catch(e){
                //if(navigator.mimeTypes ["application/x-shockwave-flash"] != undefined) hasFlash = true;
                //alert("status @2 "+ hasFlash );
                try
                {
                    if(navigator.mimeTypes["application/x-shockwave-flash"].enabledPlugin)
                    {
                        //return (navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash 2.0"] || navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"]).description.replace(/\D+/g, ",").match(/^,?(.+),?$/)[1];
                        hasFlash = true;
                    }
                }
                catch(e)
                {
                    hasFlash = false;
                }
            }
            alert("status @44 "+ navigator.mimeTypes ["application/x-shockwave-flash"] );
            return hasFlash;
        }

        function supports_canvas()
        {
            //alert(!!document.createElement('canvas').getContext);
            return !!document.createElement('canvas').getContext;
        }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="ifrm" name="ifrm_wrapper" frameborder="0" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="No"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer to Myself

Ok, so I found that Azure Web App doesn't have all mime types set, And all jquery files with json extension are blocked by default, so you've got to register this mime type in StaticContent clause of your web.config and add

```html
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
```

Source [json support in Azure Web Apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/africaapps/2013/06/07/how-to-serve-static-json-files-from-a-windows-azure-website/)